# No more mirrors are available

Tags: linux

the oracle linux have this error.No more mirrors are available,Required data could not be found on any of the configured software sources. There were no more download mirrors that could be tried.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nkjb.png)

what's the reason,how to slove it?

Answer (score 1):

This message means that package you're trying to install not available on any repository.

Try add official repositories accordingly to the following instruction:

http://yum.oracle.com/getting-started.html

And run in console:

```
# yum clean all && yum makecache
```

Also, old links may be not available now, or may be access only with HTTPS. Check baseurl's and mirrors lists in /etc/yum.repos.d/.repo

Click "More details", there may be useful information.

Check package name, or try search it at first with `# yum search $package_name` or `# yum search all $package_name`